# Handle mousemove stop with RxJs

Tags: events, rxjs

Is there a way to identify when user stopped moving the mouse? I can't figure it out how to tell in RxJs if user stopped for let's say 2s.

When I use it like this:

```
fromEvent(document, 'mousemove').pipe(
    debounceTime(2000)
).subscribe(() => console.log("Stoped"));
```

It triggers even if I move cursor out of the screen.

Comment: Well, you can't handle events that aren't emitted by the browser so when you move mouse out of the screen browser is not emitting any events so there's nothing you can do about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on a situation, but [timeout](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/timeout) or [timeoutWith](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/timeoutWith) may work for you.

This example will emit `"stop"` every time when there was no `mousemove` events for more than 1s:

```js
const { of, defer, concat, fromEvent } = rxjs;
const { mapTo, timeoutWith, skipUntil } = rxjs.operators;

const move$ = fromEvent(document, 'mousemove').pipe(mapTo('move'));
const moveAndStop$ = move$.pipe(
  timeoutWith(
    1000, 
    defer(() => concat(
      of('stop'), 
      moveAndStop$.pipe(skipUntil(move$))
    ))
  )
);

moveAndStop$
  .subscribe(e => console.log(e));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.3.2/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">Move your mouse over me</div>
```

Comment: Ok, but how to tell, when to start the timeout? I'm struggling with that.

Comment: @Gabriel I've updated my answer with code example for you